# Select rows of matrix that are higher than a given row

Tags: list-manipulation

Imagine I have the following matrix:
`X={{0,0,0},{1,0,1},{1,1,1},{1,2,1},{3,3,3}}`. 
I want to select the sublists that are greater or equal than this list `T={0,1,1}`. Greater in the sense that `X[[]]-T` has no negative entries. The output should look like `R={{1,1,1},{1,2,1},{3,3,3}}`, since all elements of the sublists are equal of greater than the elements of the list T compared element by element. Thanks for help!

Thanks for the quick answers. I have searched myself meanwhile and found this one:

```
Higher[C_] := Select[B, NonNegative[Min[#[[]] - C[[]]]] &];
```

Does it seem right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
X = Table[RandomInteger[{-10, 10}], {30}, {3}]
```

**1**

Faster

```
Select[X, And @@ Thread[# > {0, 1, 1}] &]
```

or slower one:

```
Select[X, (! MemberQ[# - {0, 1, 1}, _?NonPositive]) &]
```

Comment: Thanks Kuba! It works perfectly! Which one do you recommend I use for efficiency purposes! The one you suggested or the one I found above? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

If `x` is short then it probably doesn't matter much how you do it,
but if `x` is long then `Pick` is clearly faster than either `Select`.
The trick is to operate on a few long vectors (the columns of `x`)
rather than many short vectors (the rows of `x`).

```
t = {0,1,1}; Dimensions[x = RandomInteger[3, {10^5, 3}]]
(* {100000, 3} *)

AbsoluteTiming@Dimensions@Select[x,NonNegative@Min[#-t]&]
(* {1.888830, {56520, 3}} *)

AbsoluteTiming@Dimensions@Select[x,And@@Thread[#>=t]&]
(* {2.005653, {56520, 3}} *)

AbsoluteTiming@Dimensions@Pick[x,Total@UnitStep[Transpose@x-t],3]
(* {0.275097, {56520, 3}} *)
```